# MailMessage AlternateView in outlook 2010

Tags: c#

I used the following example for creating AlternateView for mail message: http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/2.5.aspx

I set up my outlook 2010 for receiving only plain text messages: http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/read-email-as-plain-text-in-outlook-2010/

But when I received the email: I get the html message and not the plain text message.
What Am I doing wrong? 
How can I test my development?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use windows live or thunderbird, you cant test using outlook

Comment: Windows live - do you meen hotmail?

Comment: 1. Windows live - do you mean Hotmail? Hotmail received html format mails
2. How can I display  different message format when the user set his outlook to received only plain text mails

Comment: you can configure your pop/smtp in windows live mail desktop app. This article will help you how to set up to read plain text in WLM http://www.emailquestions.com/windows-live-mail/2657-increase-your-email-security-reading-all-email-plain-text.html

Comment: outlook coverts html message to plain text it doesnt use alternateview

Comment: Regarding outlook - There is a way to overcome this problem

Comment: I test my development in windows live, I sent a message with an Hebrew characters, but I get gibberish at the body of the message even though I defined message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8. Can you help me?